# Error while trying to login into DB with .env in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, .env

When I try to use env for username and password, I got an error for username and password. Can someone tell me where is the problem?

This is my app.module:

```
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
      port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT),
      username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
      password: process.env.DATABASE_PASS,
      database: process.env.DATABASE_DB,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
    }),
```

And this is my .env:

```
DATABASE_HOST="localhost"
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_USER="postgres"
DATABASE_PASS="postgres"
DATABASE_DB="crypto-management"
PORT=3000
```

I am trying to solve the problem with NextJS environmental variables.

Comment: How do you load the env variables?

Comment: Only with ConfigModule:

    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    })

How should I do it?

Comment: It is working for host and port, but for username, password and database it's not working.

Comment: Those are the default values for host and port, so they didn't come from your .env but rather the package's defaults, just FYI

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `@nestjs/config` then you should use the [`forRootAsync`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#async-configuration) method that allows you to inject the `ConfigService` and get the configuration from it.

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigService], // only needed if global is not set to true
  inject: [ConfigService],
  useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: config.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
    port: parseInt(config.get('DATABASE_PORT')),
    username: config.get('DATABASE_USER'),
    password: config.get('DATABASE_PASS'),
    database: config.get('DATABASE_DB'),
    autoLoadEntities: true,
    synchronize: true,
  })
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

step 1: please try to see by console log whether .env files are printed or not
step 2: it could be possible already a database running on port 5432. try to use a different port, please

add also logging true it also helps you to see the log file.

TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
type: 'postgres',
host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT),
username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
password: process.env.DATABASE_PASS,
database: process.env.DATABASE_DB,
autoLoadEntities: true,
synchronize: true,
logging: true,
}),